# Should I align partitions on an SSD, if so how do I do it at install time?

Tags: 10.10, partitioning, ssd

I just bought a new SSD (OCZ Vertex 2) and plan to do a clean install of Maverick on it (/home is on a separate HDD). I read that it is wise to align SSD partitions.

What advantages does it truly bring to have an aligned partition on a SSD?

And how do I create an aligned Ext4 partition for the new SSD during the installation of Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What advantages does it truly bring to have an aligned partition on a SSD?

Basically it's all about better performance. If it's really such a big deal with current generation SSDs - who knows, but aligning the partition won't hurt.

Anyways, Ubuntu's installer automatically aligns the partitions correctly. The first partition starts at sector 2048, that is after 2048 sectors á 512 Bytes = 1 MiB, and 1 MiB is evenly dividable by all common SSD block sizes.

Comment: Thanks. But just to clarify, are partitions aligned correctly even if I create them form the "Specify partitions manually" menu at install?

Comment: @Uli: Yes, they are (I just checked to make sure).

Comment: to check whether alignment is correct this question might be helpful
http://askubuntu.com/questions/50428/how-do-i-check-whether-partitions-on-my-ssd-are-properly-aligned

Answer (score 0):

Boot the LiveCD version with the default option "try" and do **partitioning first using `gparted`** and you will be all right - just make sure "Align to:" is properly set to "MiB" (by default it is since 2010 or so, but it's crucial, so better to check it).

After partitioning is done, install the GNU/Linux distro (usually there is  desktop icon prepared).

If you want to be extra sure the alignment is correct, you might do additional checking: https://askubuntu.com/a/1061235/208566

I've been always using `gparted` not only because of this, but also because some installers use MB units instead of MiB (I prefer MiB, and so does gparted)