# SSD partition and align Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, sector-size

There are some old articles like http://lifehacker.com/5837769/make-sure-your-partitions-are-correctly-aligned-for-optimal-solid-state-drive-performance that come up when you search for SSD.

Some like this one [How do I check whether partitions on my SSD are properly aligned?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50428/how-do-i-check-whether-partitions-on-my-ssd-are-properly-aligned) have dead links (http://blog.aloisiojr.com/?p=28).

So in 2016 with ubuntu 16 (using from live USB), So I still need to care about aligning my SSD disk correctly (dual boot windows).

I ask cause sometimes the shutdown is slow. Not sure if this was due to closing the wbe server, IDE etc (dev system), Or cause of align issues.

When I run the parted tool it says its fine with the commands:

> sudo parted

Within parted :

```
(parted) unit KB    
(parted) p
Number  Start        End          Size         File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB       315621kB     314573kB     ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      315621kB     420479kB     104858kB     fat32           EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      420479kB     554697kB     134218kB                     Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      559940kB     119407940kB  118848000kB  ntfs                                          msftdata
 8      119408689kB  140453609kB  21044920kB   ext4
 5      140453609kB  140925469kB  471859kB     ntfs                                          hidden, diag
 6      140927566kB  418927084kB  277999518kB  ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 7      418927084kB  471663116kB  52736033kB   ext4
 9      471782654kB  480103105kB  8320451kB    linux-swap(v1)

(parted) align-check opt 9
9 aligned
(parted)                                                                  

(parted) align-check opt 1
1 aligned
```

I understand that the tool is saying it is fine, but how is that as the 314573/4096 is not a whole number?

About my SDD:
Model KINGSTON SV300S37A480G (603ABBF0)

Size 480 GB (4,80,10,39,81,056 bytes)
GUID Partition Table
Disk is OK (33° C / 91° F)

How do I find out what correct align numbers for this? Or can I trust parted and rest easy?

Comment: My thought would be that if `parted` says it's aligned properly, it is aligned properly.

Comment: First, understand that most partitioning tools have moved to a policy of aligning partitions on 1 MiB (2048-sector) boundaries as a way of improving performance with some types of arrays and some types of new hard disks (those with 4096-byte physical sectors). See article by Rod Smith:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/
Post on 8-sector boundaries alignment by srs5694
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1685666 And can can divide all entries by 8: `sudo parted /dev/sda unit s print` or `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: @oldfred thank you for the comment. Hope you can add an answer. So new users of ubuntu like me have some time frame reference.