# SSD feels very Slow

Tags: hard-drive, hdparm

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I kind of get the feeling that my hard disk is a bit slow so I looked it up and I found this website (https://www.howtoforge.com/faq/how-to-verify-hard-disk-speed) that told me to run the command `hdparm -c1 -d1 -X 66 /dev/hda` to "tune" my hard disk.

Does anyone know what this will do to my hard disk and how it's "tuning" it?

If I should run the command, is this particular command good for my particular disk (the command has `/dev/hda` in it, while my disk is a `/dev/nvme0n1p2` for example)? Or will I need to change the command's number and/or flags ?

**EDITED QUESTION**

I realized how stupid that was because you don't need to "tune" an SSD. So now the question:

My SSD is really slow, like when I compress, copy, and move files.

Ubuntu 20.04

Dell Inspiron 17 3793

Comment: Hello. Is your disk not a SSD Solid State Disk? If so you do not tune it it has no moving parts. Does that link say it is for your disk?

Comment: @David Whoops its an SSD drive. So there's no way to make my disk "faster"?

Comment: That I do not know but I would not be doing what that web site says. Maybe do a Google search on Can a SSD made to be faster?

Comment: What makes you *feel* your disk is slow? Are most of the applications you run snap-based? You can benchmark your SSD in the Disks application by clicking on the gear (next to the square "stop" button), then choosing "Benchmark Partition". If your NVMe device is reporting read speeds that do not meet expectations, [edit] your question to include as much benchmarking detail as possible, including the brand/model of the computer and SSD ‍

Comment: @matigo Compressing, copying, moving, etc. files takes really long compared to my mac and other computers. I included information as you requested a well.

Comment: Have you checked your partition alignment? https://askubuntu.com/questions/50428/how-do-i-check-whether-partitions-on-my-ssd-are-properly-aligned#240006